# how to get row having least value from a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a written a mysql query comprising a couple of joins, and the result is as follows.

```
id | title | type   |    rent
------------------------------
1    abc     low         100
2    xyz     low         200
2    xyz     mid         150
2    xyz     high        300
3    mno     low         600
3    mno     mid         200
```

I would like to have result that group (`group by`) `title` having 'least rent'.

PLZ help.

---

I would like to have the following result set

```
    id | title | type    |    rent
    ------------------------------
    1  |  abc  |   low  |     100
    ------------------------------
    2  |  xyz  |   mid  |     150
    ------------------------------
    3  |  mno  |   mid  |     200
    ------------------------------
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: i have tried 'group by id order by rent' but it just returns the first  row

Comment: Are you looking for all the rows in the group that have the minimum rent?  Or, are you looking for the group whose sum(rent) is the smallest?

Comment: Yep i am looking for all the (title's) having least rent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT title, MIN(rent) AS minrent
   FROM tablename
   GROUP BY title 
) AS t2  ON t1.title = t2.title 
        AND t1.rent  = t2.minrent;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0b89/1)

This will give you:

```
| ID | TITLE | TYPE | RENT |
----------------------------
|  1 |   abc |  low |  100 |
|  2 |   xyz |  mid |  150 |
|  3 |   mno |  mid |  200 |
```

This will give you the least rent for each `title`.

---

**However:** If you are looking for only the tile which has the latest `rent` then you can do this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename AS t1
ORDER BY rent  
LIMIT 1
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0b89/3)

This will give you this row:

```
| ID | TITLE | TYPE | RENT |
----------------------------
|  1 |   abc |  low |  100 |
```

**Note that:** If there are duplicates `Rent` that has the same min rent, then this won't give you those duplicate. In this case use the way [@user2009463](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15203269/722783) suggested.

Comment: i am srry i didnt understood that

Comment: @user1504606 - Have you tried it? Did it give you the result you are trying to achieve? The first query I posted uses the joined subquery to get the min rent for each title, then inner join the outer query to get the rest of the rows that has the least rent. The second one will give you only one row which has the least rent. Not sure whether this is what you are looking for or not. If not please edit your question and show the result set that you are looking for.

Comment: i am sorry Mahmoud Gamal it didnt gave me desired results, appreciate your inputs though.

Comment: @user1504606 The first query will give you the same result that you showed in the updated question. See [**this demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0b89/1).

Comment: but all the value comes from 5 different tables and i have used 4 mysql joins

Comment: and now i cant find a way to put all of these suggestions

Comment: @user1504606 - You didn't say that in your question. Can you please update your question and show me that query will the 4 different tables with the tables structures? this will be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: sorry i cant disclose the table structure and the query, i guess i'll write a php script that will do that.....thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table_name
where rent = (select min(rent) from table_name)
group by title;
```

Comment: the table above is the result of joins, i cant find a way to put your query within mine...